# Inherit from a class given as an argument

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, arguments

*My setup: I am coding in python 3.7, with spyder4, on a windows10 machine.*

### Context

I am writing classes for a package. It is some kind of handler for classes defined in another package that I am importing.

Here is a simplified version of the situation:

```
# This I cannot modify, as they are in the package
class Letter_Class():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class A(Letter_Class):
    def source(self):
        print("from class A")
    def funcA(self):
        print("from class A")

class B(Letter_Class):
    def source(self):
        print("from class B")
    def funcB(self):
        print("from class B")

class C(Letter_Class):
    def source(self):
        print("from class C")
    def funcC(self):
        print("from class C")

# This I can modify
class Dynamic(Letter_Class):
    def __new__(self, name, this_class): # -------- issue lies here? --------
        obj = this_class(name)
        return obj

    def new_func(self):
        print("function defined in dynamic class")
```

The classes `Letter_Class`, `A`, `B`, `C`have already been defined by someone else (in that 'other package' I am handling) and I cannot change them. I want to make a class, here called "Dynamic", who will inherit from a class given as an argument. It must still have the (many, many) methods that I wish to add such as `new_func()`. I cannot know in advance which `Letter_Class` child is used.

Classes `A`, `B`, `C` have both polymorphic and specific methods, such as `source()` and `funcA()`. Because of that, **I cannot make `Dynamic` inherit from these classes**. It would have been too easy.

### Problem

If I execute the previous and the following code:

```
# user executes in main: 
instance = Dynamic("test name", B)
print(instance.name)
instance.source()
instance.funcB()
instance.new_func()
```

I get:

```
test name  
from class B  
from class B  

AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'new_func'
```

The instance is created, `source()` and `funcB()` are executed without any problem. 
Then, an attribute error is raised, because a `Device` object was not truly created.

Could anyone explain to me what to put in the `__new__()` constructor function to actually return an instance of the `Device` class, with the proper inheritance from `this_class`? I would be very grateful.
[This discusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40382067/can-a-python-class-not-inherit-from-multiple-classes-but-have-a-choice-of-inh) seems to address the issue, but in a different context and I cannot apply the suggested solution.

Comment: " I want to make a class, here called "Dynamic", who will inherit from a class given as an argument." That doesn't make much sense. Inheritance happens *when a class is defined* not when an instance is created. There's probably some hacky way you can get this done, but you almost certainly shouldn't. Likely, you just want some sort of proxy class.

Comment: So, here was a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746709/can-i-choose-the-parent-class-of-a-class-from-a-fixed-set-of-parent-classes-cond/56747123#56747123) where I gave an answer that demonstrated how to define a proxy class.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your link. I had come up with a solution like yours, by redirecting the calls to a private variable, of the class I want to wrap. I was lacking the `__getattr__()` special method, and that does the trick perfectly. A proxy class is exactly what I was looking for, I will see if I can implement that in my project. 
Many thanks

Comment: Just watch out, proxying like this won't work with dunder methods, e.g. `__eq__` or `__str__`. Often that's fine... [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742625/dynamically-adding-builtin-methods-to-point-to-a-propertys-built-ins/59743116#59743116) a workaround I cooked up in case it isn't, and some other answers if that will be a problem for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solutions

I have found a solution to **MY** problem (thanks to the SO community). To all coders searching for a solution to **THEIR** problem, the use case might make you want to choose one of these two solutions:

### factory functions

Using a factory function that builds your class - see Reblochon Masque's answer for that.

### using a proxy class

This was suggested by juanpa.arrivillaga in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746709/can-i-choose-the-parent-class-of-a-class-from-a-fixed-set-of-parent-classes-cond/56747123#56747123).

This is the solution I believe I will be using from now on:

```
# classes Letter_Class, A, B, and C are the same as in the "Context" section (above)  
class Proxy():
    """ attempt to make a transparent proxy
    """
    def __init__(self, name, letterclass, *args, **kwargs):
        self.letter = letterclass(name, *args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, attribute):
        return getattr(self.letter, attribute)


class Dynamic(Proxy):
    """ My actual class and its methods
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # anything else to initiate the instance

    def new_func(self):
        print("calling a method defined in the Dynamic class")
```

I can now execute:

```
instance = Dynamic("foo bar", B)
print(f"instance is called: '{instance.name}'")
instance.source()
instance.funcB()
instance.new_func()
```

I will get:

```
instance is called: 'foo bar'
from class B
from class B
calling a method defined in the Dynamic class
```

Any calls to the attributes that are **NOT** defined in the `Dynamic` class will be redirected to `self.letter`, with the magic method: `__getattr__()`. Using `__getattribute__()` instead would redirect **ALL** calls to `self.letter` instead.

I chose this approach specifically because I expect my users to be building their own type of `Dynamic` class; I find it simpler to make an intermediate proxy class.

This resource was also helpful, and has clues to make a much more *transparent* proxy class: [Object proxying](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/). I did not attempt to implement this though.

So, thanks for the help folks, Take care.
XC

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're setting `instance` to equal the return value of the `Letter_Class`; `instance` is a `B` object, and has no relationship with `Dynamic`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I had happening, and I didn't know how to have it otherwise. I didn't explicit that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a factory function that builds your class instances using the given class to inherit from:

```
class Letter_Class:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class A(Letter_Class):
    def source(self):
        print("from class A")
    def funcA(self):
        print("from class A")

class B(Letter_Class):
    def source(self):
        print("from class B")
    def funcB(self):
        print("from class B")

class C(Letter_Class):
    def source(self):
        print("from class C")
    def funcC(self):
        print("from class C")


def make_dynamic_letterclass_factory(cls):
    """makes an returns a Letter_Class subclass instance that inherits
    from the class passed as argument
    """
    class Dynamic(cls):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def new_func(self):
            print("function defined in dynamic class")

    return Dynamic()


a = make_dynamic_letterclass_factory(A)
a.source(), a.funcA()

b = make_dynamic_letterclass_factory(B)
b.source(), b.funcB()

c = make_dynamic_letterclass_factory(C)
c.source(), c.funcC()
```

#### output:

```
from class A
from class A
from class B
from class B
from class C
from class C
```

Comment: This does seem to do the trick ! 
However, with the way I am designing this package, I will rather go with a proxy class proposed by @juanpa.arrivillaga in a higher comment. I will soon update my final solution